# Align 2 boxes next to eachother, while one of them has position: fixed;

Tags: css, html, position, alignment

I want to align two boxes like this:

[image]

The left panel width moves in the range 260-320px ( depending on the browser-width ) and has `position: fixed`, while the other panel should take the remaining part of the browser.

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NTwUY/4/

The problem is that they go over each other, instead of one next to other.
I don't want to use javascript for this and I can't just set `margin-left: 260px` on the second because it's responsive.

Comment: Why does one of them have position absolute anyway?

Comment: Float with position ?? Any reason why you need both ??

Comment: I mean fixed, not absolute, sorry for the mistake :(

Comment: The code in the fiddle is not responsive.

Comment: Because the field box is too small, my goal is to make the content box stay next to the panel, not overit.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NTwUY/2/

You have to give `fixed` rule to the `#holder` layer:

```
#holder {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#panel {
    float:left;
    background-color: green;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 320px;
}

#content {
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NTwUY/4/ try to scroll in the result box I want the content to be next to the panel, not under it

Comment: Doesn't have to be fixed the second layer?

Comment: No only the panel(left) should have fixed position, so it will be always there nomatter of scrolling. The content panel will be really long and it shouldn't be fixed

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that the width of panel is scalable.